# ungroup data points with the same y value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I am trying to draw a bar graph to illustrate the trend when intervention attempts increase, Duration of sleep trend increase.
[image]

Here's the graph I have. As you can see, ggplot2 has grouped all duration of sleep based on their intervention attempt (this would make the duration of sleep around 28 hours collectively, which is confusing). I was wondering if there's a way to somehow group the duration of sleep but make them spread out, instead of being on top of each other.
[image]

```
#Data cleansing
library(tidyverse)
sleep_data <- read_csv("mock-data.csv")
sleep_data <- sleep_data[1:7,1:6]

library(hms)
library(lubridate) 

#Data Visualization
intervention_rating <- sleep_data$`Intervention rating`
intervention <- sleep_data$Intervention
bedtime <- sleep_data$Bedtime
wakeup_time <- sleep_data$`Wake up time`

sleepTime <- function(bed, wake){
  wake <- paste(Sys.Date(), wake)
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date(), bed)
  d <- apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
  adjust <- -(d < 0)
  tmpbed <- paste(Sys.Date() + adjust, bed)
  apply(data.frame(tmpbed, wake), 1, function(x) difftime(x[2], x[1], units = "hours"))
}

sleep_time_per_hour <- sleepTime(bedtime, wakeup_time) 
sleep_data <- sleep_data[1:7,1:7]
# 
ggplot(data = sleep_data, aes(y=sleep_time_per_hour, x=intervention)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        theme_light() +
        ylim(c(0,50)) +
        xlab("Intervention Attempt") +
        ylab("Duration of Sleep") +
        geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Comment: Try to replace `geom_bar(stat="identity")` with `  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = “dodge”)`

Comment: You should not add data as images. We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).